# C# function to import excel file choose any two column and add them cell by cell and paste out put in other column

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, winforms, desktop-application

**Hi everyone i need ha c# window app program that import a excel file and there should be option to select any two column and than add them cell by cell and there should be other option to select any column to paste addition result of previous two columns 
please help me**

Comment: Amongst the other problems with this question, why both c# AND vb tags ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Open XML from Microsoft, in nuget package "DocumentFormat.OpenXml".

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK

> The Open XML SDK provides tools for working with Office Word, Excel,
>   and PowerPoint documents. It supports scenarios such as:
>
> - High-performance generation of word-processing documents, spreadsheets, and presentations.
> - Extraction of data from Excel documents.
> - etc